# Was there an official set of Composite Cables for the PS1/2/3 using the "Premium" RCA Connectors?

Tags: ps3, ps2, ps1

The Composite video cables that came with all of the PS1, PS2 and PS3 models was a simple AV Multi to 3x standard RCA Connectors for Video and the Left and Right audio channels.

[image]

On the other hand, the official Component, D-Terminal and S Video Cables sold separately uses a more "Premium" type of connector, where the exterior has a silver color with a strip indicating the purpose of the individual connectors.

[image]

Was there ever an official Composite cable using this type of connector? If so, was it region specific (like D-Terminal), timed exclusive or available worldwide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was there an official set of Composite Cables for the PS1/2/3 using the "Premium" RCA Connectors?

## Yes

You're after **SCPH-10500**, sometimes known as 'gold plated' composite A/V cables (due to the RCA end/tip being gold in colour):

[image: Composite A/V cables with gold tips]

For reference, the same 'style' of connector was used for both S-Video (**SCPH-10480**) and Component (**SCPH-10490**) cables. There is an official RGB SCART cable too (**SCPH-1050**)

It's also worth mentioning that the PS1 does not support Component output, leaving you with the other aforementioned options for video output.

Here's a table for neatness sake:

| Model No. | Type |
| --- | --- |
| SCPH-10480 | S-Video |
| SCPH-10490 | Component (YPbPr) |
| SCPH-10500 | Composite |
| SCPH-1050 | SCART (RGB) |